# MVVM Databinding to Database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding, datagridview

I am looking for a smart way of binding a table from a database to a `DataGridView` in WPF. I was thinking it would be nice if I could bind an `IQueryable` object directly to the `DataGridView`. I am not sure yet, how I do the binding to the `View` trough the `ModelView` (as in which datatypes for the lists, etc).

I think it would be very easy to just bind the View directly to the database, but that would not be a nice MVVM approach, would it?

Should I use `ObservableCollection`?

It is important to point out that I would like the data to be updated automatically when something changes on the database.

Also I am using **EntityFramework** for the database.

```
ProductionEntities _DbContext = new ProductionEntities();
IQueryable<Article> myArticles = from article in _DbContext.Articles
                                 select article;
```

---

EDIT:

Is it a good idea to just expose the DbContext (or the DataTable of it) trough the ModelView?

```
private ProductionEntities _DbContext;

public ProductionEntities DbContext
{
    get { return _DbContext; }
}
```

Comment: That would be an incredibly poor developmental decision, as you would effectively be tying your database dependencies all the way through your application to the UI. Most developers create a separate data source project. *Updating data automatically* is usually achieved by polling the database at regular intervals and updating the UI properties as and when appropriate.

Comment: I tought so... Actually on Winforms I managed to get my DataGridView to sync with the database automatically. This is not possible anymore in WPF? How do developers usually deal with the data changes when they use EntityFramework? Do they handle them in the ViewModel and then perform the changes to the Entity or what? All examples I found from Microsoft just ignore the MVVM pattern and they just bind the database directly to the view.

Comment: You should hide all SQL related code on some backend service and far far away from your clients. Create a backend that does the heavy lifting and communicates with the frontend through WCF, SOAP or REST, or both :) Frankly I would recommend NHibernate as a dataprovider for ORM's/Entitites. EF don't get me started ;) Your frontend shouldn't even know of SQL nor any connections to it.

Comment: The problem is that the application should be a small administration window. I agree that a service would be the best way to achieve this, but it is a bit too much work for a single application running on one single PC.